# 02-08 06:44:43.262: E/dalvikvm(503): Could not find class , referenced from method RSSManager.run

Tags: android, rss, runtime, rss-reader

Hi i have to develop one android BBC_NEWS_READER application from [here](https://github.com/okey666/BBC-News-Reader)

Here am getting following error:

```
02-08 06:44:43.262: E/dalvikvm(503): Could not find class 'org.mcsoxford.rss.RSSReader', 
referenced from method com.digitallizard.bbcnewsreader.RSSManager.run
```

also am getting below errors :

```
     -08 06:44:44.503: E/AndroidRuntime(503): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
     02-08 06:44:44.503: E/AndroidRuntime(503): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
              org.mcsoxford.rss.RSSReader
     02-08 06:44:44.503: E/AndroidRuntime(503):     at 
      com.digitallizard.bbcnewsreader.RSSManager.run(RSSManager.java:63)
     02-08 06:44:44.503: E/AndroidRuntime(503):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

How can i clear these error.please give me idea ???

Comment: Did you add the class name in android manifest file?

Comment: yes i didnot add class name on my androidmanifest file.ok i ll check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.First of all, check if your source is where it is mentioned in the error log.

2.If it is, check if you've made any typing mistakes

3.If it still isn't working, it would be easier (In my opinion) to create a new project and rename what is missing (I've done this several times already and it has always worked) Of course, make sure you copy all of your code

your error does not belong to the manifest, cuz this would be mentioned in the log like this: `have youe declared <yourClass> in AdroidManifest.xml?`

Comment: i have done your 3rd step.now its worked...but i wish to need one help...where can i find these RSS feed Url ???